# Grails 3 No tests found for given includes: [*.controlerName]

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I've worked through the Grails tutorial at https://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html. I'm using Grails 3.3.9, Groovy 2.4.15 and IntelliJ Idea 2019 2.2

I got as far as the testing section (section 9) when I encountered this weird issue.
The stub test, created automatically after every Grails create-~ command, looks like this:

> package org.grails.guides
>
> import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest import
>   spock.lang.Specification
>
> class MakeControllerSpec extends Specification implements
>   ControllerUnitTest {
>
> ```
> def setup() {
> }
>
> def cleanup() {
> }
>
> void "test something"() {
>     expect:"fix me"
>         true == false
> } }
> ```

When executed with the command:

> ./grailsw test-app *.MakeControllerSpec

Naturally fails with the following output:

> Execution failed for task ':test'.
>
> > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/Groovy/grails-practice/myApp/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

That's all good and as expected. Naturally, when the index.html file is opened, the test results are displayed, with details of the failing test.
But when I change the "assert" section of the test to:

> true == true

Then run the test, the output is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
>
>   > No tests found for given includes: [*.MakeControllerSpec]

The terminal output (both IntelliJ and git bash were used) is stating that no tests were found.
But when I open the index.html file and view the test results, I can see that the test was in fact executed, and that it passed. 
Upon experimentation, it seems that any tests that pass, display the  "No tests found..." message, but tests that fail do not.
It appears to be a logging issue rather than an issue with the test itself.

Comment: What do you get when you run `./gradlew test --tests *MakeController*`

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you mention there.

Comment: Your output mentions `:integrationTest` but the test you show looks like a unit test.  Is the test defined under `src/test/groovy/`?

Comment: I suspect that what has happened is when you set the assertion to `true == true`, that allowed the test to pass and then the build went on to run your integration tests.  If you use Gradle to run the tests then `./gradlew test` will run unit tests, `./gradlew integrationTest` (or `./gradlew iT` for short) will run the integration tests and `./gradlew check` will run unit tests and then integration tests.  Your output suggests that something caused the build to think you wanted to run an integration test with the specified pattern, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks! When I used the -unit option, the console output was a success message. As you said, it must have completed the unit test and then proceeded to the integration test for the same name and not found it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!